# How do I find out if my laptop's Wifi receiver supports 5Ghz networks?

Tags: windows-7, networking, wireless-networking, router

I have a Windows 7 laptop which does not show 5 GHz wireless lans in the wireless network settings.

How can I find out if the 5 GHz range is just not configured (i.e. Switched on) or if this is not supported by the hardware?

Laptop is asus. 4 months old. Windows 7 Premium N55SL series

The laptop has a centrino wireless n 1030 and when i look in its properties, advanced tab
i see:

- 802.11n channel width for band 2.4 and value is 20 Mhz only (other option there is auto)
- 802.11n mode (opt. there are enabled or disabled) and its enabled
- ad hoc channel 802.11b/g value here is 11 (you can add or subtract numbers)
- ad hoc QoS mode here value is WMM disabled

other blahblah values and later i see

- wireless mode and value is 3.802.11b/g (other opt. are /b or /g)

Driver is 14.2.1.1

I have a new fiber router that can broadcast on both frequencies so I would like to use them both (router is ok. My phone sees both the wifi networks)

Comment: [If using Linux see this question/answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137894/3285).

Answer (score 13):

The general solution on Windows is to run the following in Command Prompt:

```
netsh wlan show drivers
```

Look for **Radio types supported** in the output. If you see `802.11a` in the list, 5 GHz networks are supported. Otherwise, as in this example, only 2.4 GHz networks are supported:

```
Radio types supported     : 802.11n 802.11g 802.11b
```

Comment: This should be accepted as the answer.

Comment: Please note, there's a slight chance that **802.11n** is shown without 802.11a or 802.11ac and 5Ghz is still supported.

Answer (score 1):

You can also tell it does not support the 5GHz band because it is only 802.11b/g compatible. `b` and `g` don't use 5GHz, unlike `a` (always), `n` (sometimes), and `ac` (always).

Comment: @EvanCarroll I think you meant “‘sometimes’ is not a helpful answer”. You’ll note that my answer is not, in fact, simply “sometimes,” but rather pointing out that by examining the protocol(s) supported, one can usually infer whether the 5GHz band is supported. If you see `a` or `ac`, you have 5GHz. If you see `n`, you *might* (but probably not if you don’t see `a`, since otherwise there is little reason to drop backwards-compatibility with `a`).

Comment: He already said he had `802.11n`. Your question is easily reduced to it *sometimes* has it. That's not a good answer. For comparison, [this method on linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/137894/3285) tells you definitively. The question is how to do that on Windows. I don't know, but that's the *right* answer.

Comment: I see. I interpreted OP’s statement that “wireless mode and value is 3.802.11b/g (other opt. are /b or /g)” to mean that it was only a b/g card and that it lacked "n" entirely. I’m still not sure that I’m wrong; why wouldn’t "n" be an available mode? Odd it seems to allow configuring "n" channel width but not, you know, using "n"

Comment: I'm not sure wtf you're talking about or how you're confused. If I give you a card. And, it has no labels how do you, with only mucking around in Linux, know that it does or does not support 5ghz? May/sometimes is not an acceptable it answer. It either does or does not and I want to know which one.

Comment: Evan seems to be missing the point here. Having 'n' in the list is not definitive and can be either, therefore you have to look at the *other* entries in the list to determine for sure, and *ignore* the value of 'n' because it *sometimes* can be 5Ghz it cannot be trusted to tell you *always*.
Alan is also off though, because the particular option referred to in the Intel drivers does not display N (or AC) when it's available, it only ever lists (a subset of) a/b/g.

Answer (score 0):

No, that wireless card does not appear to support the 5GHz band, just the 2.4GHz:

```
Bands   2.4 GHz
```

<sup>[Source](http://ark.intel.com/products/59481/Intel-Centrino-Wireless-N-1030-Single-Band)</sup>